# A unique 'code' to represent a 2d array

Tags: java

I've made a game that randomly generates mazes, the maze is stored in a 2d array.
each integer in the array represents the number of walls that cell has.

It's based on the java example here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze

To allow people to share a unique maze i'm trying to find a way to convert the array into a string or an integer that can be generated by one user, copied and then pasted into another game which will then load the same maze.

The user can select the size of the maze up to 25x25 so simply printing each value (2|16|4|20...) would be incredibly long.

If converting it to a 'code' isn't possible are there any other ways it can be done without using a file?

Comment: What about [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)?

Comment: How is 25*25 incredibly long?

Comment: *"25x25 so simply printing each value (2|16|4|20...) would be incredibly long."*  25 x 25 x 4 (assuming 4 chars stores a position), amounts to just 2500 bytes.  That is 'credibly short'.

Comment: An arbitrary 25*25 integers take 25*25*32 = 20000 bit = 2500 byte to represent in the general case. Of course, if there's a limit on the integers, you can get away with less (e.g. if the ints are actually in 1..4, you can get down to 25*25*4 bit).

Comment: The array contents themselves **are** the code representing itself completely. (You could obviously compress them using some method specific to your data, but for a first attempt you might as well just write it out straightforwardly and pass it through gzip. Or not, because 2500 bytes is peanuts.)

Comment: I've not tried anything yet, I don't know where to start.

I'll look into Serialization, it seems promising.

Comment: @AndrewThompson and millimoose: For an in-memory representation, 25*25 integers are really small, yes. But OP wants to create a representation *for users to share* (like seeds for minecraft worlds).

Comment: @delnan. So what? 2500 bytes represent 31 lines of typical 80-characters-long lines of text. It's incredibly short, even without any attempt at compression.

Comment: @delnan Serialize, gzip, base64, pray it's short enough.

Comment: even if each cell could be represented by 1 character 25x25 would still take 625 characters. thats not short for a user to copy and paste.

Comment: @AlexMusk Then "copy/paste" is a silly requirement unless you're willing to go the procedural generation route, which requires having pseudorandom generators that reliably produce identical sequences of output.

Comment: @JBNizet Compared to the 64 bit number other implementations of this feature use, it *is* really large. More specifically, several orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: @millimoose "Pray" is not an acceptable solution in software engineering. Unless the problem is far too complex to be understood, but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: @delnan YAGNI is a perfectly acceptable solution in software engineering. Yes, procedural generation is a clever approach. I just dispute that the degree of cleverness is *necessary*.

Comment: @millimoose The requirement (in the form of the question) clearly do include the feature we're debating here, so how can you say "you ain't gonna need it"? YAGNI would mean not doing it *at all*. Moreover, it doesn't take much knowledge of information theory to see that it being "small enough" (which I'll take to mean "a couple dozen ASCII characters" here) is really rather small. What's worse, the alternative *is actually easier*: OP is already generating the content randomly, so using the PRNG seed is trivial and natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the seed for the random number generator. The seed fully determines the output of the random number generator.

Assuming you are using `java.util.Random` to generate the random numbers, instead of using the default constructor `new Random()` use

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
// store the seed somewhere
// so you can generate the same sequence of random numbers again
Random rng = new Random(seed);
```

To make a short "code" that can be given to users for sharing, you can convert the number to hex or base 36:

```
String code = Long.toString(seed, 36); // codes like heeho82h
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're randomly creating the values for that array, you only need the state of the PRNG that produced those values to re-generate them. That's at the same time the biggest weakness and strength of all pseudo-random number generators.

As most PRNGs don't allow retrieving and setting the state, or have a pretty huge state (a Mersenne Twister has a few kilobyte of state internally), you may want to use the seed instead. Of course, then you must create a new PRNG (or reset an existing one) for level generation.

To make the number human-readable, you should just render it in some number base. Base 10 makes it obvious it's a number and is easiest to generate and parse. Base 16 (hexadecimal) and base 64 yield shorter, more obscure "codes". Padding it to be fixed-length regardless of the actual value is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Serialization` concept to save the state of `2-D array` and then retrieve it back using deserialization. Here is the simple Demo to save a `2-D array` state and then read it back . I hope it would be of your help:

```
import java.io.*;
class ArraySerialization 
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    ByteArrayInputStream bins;
    public void saveState(Object obj)throws Exception
    {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.close();
    }
    public int[][] readState()throws Exception
    {
        bins = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream oins = new ObjectInputStream(bins);
        Object obj = oins.readObject();
        oins.close();
        return (int[][])obj;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int arr[][]= {
                        {1,2,3},
                        {4,5,7}
                    };
        ArraySerialization ars = new ArraySerialization();
        System.out.println("Saving state...");
        ars.saveState(arr);
        System.out.println("State saved..");
        System.out.println("Retrieving state..");
        int j[][] = ars.readState();
        System.out.println("State retrieved..And the retrieved array is:");
        for (int i =0 ; i < j.length ; i++ )
        {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < j[i].length ; k++)
            {
                System.out.print(j[i][k]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it uses a random generator, it is in fact a deterministic process. You can repeat it by knowing the random seed. Just share the random seed, as mentioned by Joni. Anyway, if you want to share the data: a NxN mesh has NxN inner walls, and considering it takes 1 bit to store presence/absence of a wall, you will need NxN bits to store the maze. In this way you can store a 90x90 maze in 1kb.